# Windows Installer XML relative Path for Patch

Tags: msbuild, wix, patch, pyro, wix3.8

I'm using the Microsoft Team Foundation Server to manage and Deploy Setups for my Applications.
My Setups are WiX-Setups with relative Paths.

p.e. 
Components

```
<Component Id="Anwendung.exe" Directory="INSTALLLOCATION" Guid="*">
<File Id="Anwendung.exe" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceFiles)\Anwendung.exe" />
</Component>
```

Variables.wxi:

`<Include>`

`<?define SourceFiles = "..\OutputFiles"?>`

`</Include>`

Setups are building correctly.
The Problem: I'm using Torch and Pyro to generate Patches for my applications.
I'm using a pure Wix Patch Project with manipulated build events and additional linker information

**(Pre Build - Torch) 
(Post Build - Pyro) 
(Linker additional Parameters - output as wixmsp)**

When I build my Patch, I'm getting 579Failures.
(1x)

*Error  776 The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.8\bin\pyro.exe" Patch.wixmsp -out Patch.msp -t AnwendungBaseline diff.wixmst" exited with code 103.

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\wix2010.targets*

and (578x)

*Error 322 The system cannot find the file '..\SourceFiles\Anwendung.exe'.  C:\Patch\Client\Upgrade\Setup\ComponentMain.wxs*

I'm sure it's not resolving the paths from the sourcesetups correctly.
Could anybody help me? Rob Arnson , Rob Mensching, Heath Steward? Please :)

Comment: with full-qualified Paths it's working, but in combination with the tfs (Team Foundation Server), the usage of relativ paths is nonavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

To get around issues like this, you can write a custom build activity for TFS to update variables in your WiX config file with fully qualified paths. For instance, you can create a build activity that takes in the path to a config file, the name of a variable, and value for that variable, and  then write the new value to the config file. You can keep the config file with relative paths checked into source control, but then the build will update the config file to use the fully qualified path just for the build.

If you are unfamiliar with creating custom build activities, there is a great blog series on it [here](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/29/customize-team-build-2010-e28093-part-4-create-your-own-activity.aspx). The link is for TFS 2010 but the process is similar for TFS 2012.

Comment: Thanks, but that was not the problem. The Problem was, that I've used the .wixmsp-files for generating the patch (with Torch and Pyro). The wixmsp Files included only the references to the files. Now i use .wixout Files, which consists all Files. Now The TFS will work with it and i don't have to install the Setups before generating a diff. My test with relativ paths was successfull.Thanks for the help.